# Infimum of norms of elements in a hyperplane

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In a Banach space X, given a norm one bounded linear functional $f$ and $c\in \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$, define $H = \big\{ x\in X \,\vert\, f(x) = c\big\}$ and $\inf H$ = $\inf_{h\in H} \|h\|$.

1. Is there a necessary condition for $\inf H = \vert\, c\,\vert$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your linear functional means "complex linear", then $\inf H = |c|$ will always be true if $\lVert f \rVert = 1$.

On the one hand, since $\lVert f \rVert = 1$, we can choose a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of norm $1$ elements in $X$ such that $|f(x_n)| > 0$ and $|f(x_n)| \rightarrow \lVert f \rVert = 1$. Replacing $x_n$ with $\dfrac{|f(x_n)|}{f(x_n)} \cdot x_n$, we can assume that $f(x_n) \in (0, + \infty)$ and $f(x_n) \rightarrow 1$. Apparently $\dfrac{c}{f(x_n)} \cdot x_n \in H$ and $\left\lVert \dfrac{c}{f(x_n)} \cdot x_n \right\rVert = \dfrac{|c|}{|f(x_n)|} \rightarrow |c|$, so $\inf H \le |c|$.

On the other hand, if $\inf H < |c|$, then there exists a sequence $\{ y_n \} \subseteq H$, $f(y_n) = c$ and $\lVert y_n \rVert \rightarrow \inf H$, which leads to a contradiction that $|c|=|f(y_n)| \le \lVert f \rVert \lVert y_n \rVert \rightarrow \inf H < |c|$.

About your second question, is there really any difference between real and complex hyperplanes in a complex Banach space? I am confused about your motivation of asking this question.

This qusetion is more suitable for MSE, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now realize that there are indeed no differences between a real and a complex hyperplane.